# arraylist<hashmap<string,string>> not working

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, google-maps-android-api-2, markers

I'm wondering ,what I'm doing wrong here for two days.
I Start the following AsyncTask GetLocationsAsync.java to send a HttpPost to a PHP file on a server,

```
public class GetLocationsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>
{
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LAT = "user_current_lat";
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LONG = "user_current_long";
public static final String USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS = "user_current_address";
private Exception exception;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Context MainContext;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapActivity activity;

public GetLocationsAsyncTask(MapActivity activity, Context con)
{
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.MainContext = con;

}

public void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainContext);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if (exception == null)
    {
        activity.loadLocations(result);
    }
    else
    {
        processException();
    }
 }

@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params)
{
    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try
    {
        double PLat = Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LAT));
        double PLong = Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LONG));
        String Addr = new String(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS));
        Locq5ionsParser Lp = new LocationsParser();
        Document doc = Pp.getDocument(Addr, PLat, PLong, "Bar");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>LocationPoints = Lp.getDirection(doc);
        return LocationPoints;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
        Log.d("GetLocations", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
 }

private void processException()
{
    Toast.makeText(MainContext, "Fehler beim Auslesen der XML", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("GetLocationAsync", exception.getLocalizedMessage());
 }



}


public class LocationParser {
public LocationParser() {
}

public Document getDocument(String addr, double latitude, double longitude, String type) {
        String url = "http://**********/xmlphpshow.php";

 try {
     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
     postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Addresse", addr
             .toString()));
     postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude)
             .toString()));
     postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude)
             .toString()));
     postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "Bar"
             .toString()));
     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
     InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
     DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                     .newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(in);
     return doc;
 } catch (Exception e) {
 Log.d("LocationParser", e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
}

}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDirection(Document DirektDoc) {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> LocationItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
NodeList nl, nl2, nl3;
  // getting XML
 if (DirektDoc.equals(null)){
        Log.d("Dokument", "doc ist leer");
        return null;
     }
     try{
nl = DirektDoc.getElementsByTagName("marker");
     }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("TagName Markers", e.getMessage());
            return null;
         }


// looping through all item nodes <item>
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
   try{ 
   Node node1  = nl.item(i);
   nl3 = node1.getChildNodes();
   Node AddrNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "address"));
   String PAddr = AddrNode.getTextContent();

   //the Log shows that the addresses of each marker item was read correctly 
   Log.d("LocationParser","Adresse :" + PAddr);



   map.put("Addresse", PAddr);
   Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
   String lat = latNode.getTextContent();
   map.put("latitude", lat);
   Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
   String lng = lngNode.getTextContent();
   map.put("longitude", lng);
   Node typeNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "type"));
   String LocType = typeNode.getTextContent();
   map.put("Type", LocType);
   Node timeNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "tstamp"));
   String timeString = timeNode.getTextContent();
   map.put("TimeStamp", timeString);


           LocationItems.add(map);
   }catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("LocationParser", e.getMessage());
   }
}

return LocationItems;
}


private int getNodeIndex(NodeList NodeInl, String nodename) {
for (int i = 0; i < NodeInl.getLength(); i++) {
     if (NodeInl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename)){
         return i;
}

}
return -1;
}
}
```

When I now try to read the Hashmap Values inside the ArrayList and create a Marker on my GoogleMap, there is only one Marker Visible.

```
public class MapActivity {
public GoogleMap googleMap;
public MapFragment mapfrag;
public Context MapContext;
public Document dc;
public MarkerOptions startMarker, ParkMarker;
public MapActivity(MapFragment gmapfrag, Context con){
    this.mapfrag = gmapfrag;
    this.googleMap = mapfrag.getMap();
    this.MapContext = con;
}
 public void initilizeMap() {
        try {
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);


            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MapContext, "Karte konnte nicht erstellt werden. Versuchen 
            sie es zu einem Späteren Zeitpunkt erneut.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }               
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MapContext, "Karte konnte nicht erstellt werden. Versuchen 
       sie es zu einem Späteren Zeitpunkt erneut.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
 public void loadMarkers(double Mylati, double Mylongi, String aDdR){
     googleMap.clear();
     startMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new 
     LatLng(Mylati,Mylongi)).title("Aktuelle Position");
     startMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_icon));
     googleMap.addMarker(startMarker);
     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put(GetLocationsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(Mylati));
     map.put(GetLocationsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(Mylongi));
     map.put(GetLocationsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS, String.valueOf(aDdR));
     GetLocationsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetLocationsAsyncTask(this, MapContext);
     asyncTask.execute(map);
     //setCamView(Mylati, Mylongi);
     return;
 }
 public void loadLocations(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> directionPoints){
     for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++){

         String LocAddress = directionPoints.get(i).get("Addresse");
         double LocLat = Double.parseDouble(directionPoints.get(i).get("latitude"));
         double LocLng =  
                     Double.parseDouble(directionPoints.get(i).get("longitude"));
         String LocType = directionPoints.get(i).get("Type");
         Log.d("MapActivit", "directionPoints.size beträgt: "+   
                     directionPoints.size() + LocAddress + String.valueOf(i));
         String LocTime = directionPoints.get(i).get("TimeStamp");


        googleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LocLat,LocLng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));
     }
     return;

 }
 public void setCamView(double camLat, double camLong){
     CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
     new LatLng(camLat, camLong)).zoom(12).build();
     LatLng Startposition = new LatLng(camLat, camLong);
     googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
     return;
 }
    }
```

the generated XML file looks like following:

`<markers>
    <marker>
    <address>1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA</address>
    <lat>47.610126</lat>
    <lng>-122.342834</lng>
    <type>Bar</type>
    <tstamp>2013-12-25 00:43:50</tstamp>
    </marker>
    <marker>
    <address>1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA</address>
    <lat>47.617214</lat>
    <lng>-122.326584</lng>
    <type>Bar</type>
    <tstamp>2013-12-25 00:43:50</tstamp>
    </marker>
     <marker>
    <address>2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA</address>
    <lat>47.613976</lat>
    <lng>-122.345467</lng>
    <type>Restaurant</type>
    <tstamp>2013-12-25 00:43:50</tstamp>
    </marker>
    <marker>
    <address>1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA</address>
    <lat>47.605961</lat>
    <lng>-122.340363</lng>
    <type>Bar</type>
    <tstamp>2013-12-25 00:43:50</tstamp>
    </marker>
    <marker>
    <address>1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA</address>
    <lat>47.606365</lat>
    <lng>-122.337654</lng>
    <type>Bar</type>
    <tstamp>2013-12-25 00:43:50</tstamp>
    </marker>
    </markers>`

Can anybody help me? Whats wrong with my Code?

EDIT:

The Problem was solved thanks to gaurav5430 and Ivan. See their answers below.

Comment: Shouldn't `googleMap.addMarker(Parkmarker);` be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
// looping through all item nodes <item>
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
   try{ 
   Node node1  = nl.item(i);
   nl3 = node1.getChildNodes();
   ...
   ...
```

should be

```
// looping through all item nodes <item>
HashMap<String, String> map=null;
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
   map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   try{ 
   Node node1  = nl.item(i);
   ...
   ...
   LocationItems.add(map);
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER (The OP has corrected this problem):

you seem to be adding the marker `after the end of the loop`, so `only the last marker` would be added

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++){

     String LocAddress = directionPoints.get(i).get("Addresse");
     double LocLat = Double.parseDouble(directionPoints.get(i).get("latitude"));
     double LocLng =   
                 Double.parseDouble(directionPoints.get(i).get("longitude"));
     String LocType = directionPoints.get(i).get("Type");
     Log.d("MapActivit", "directionPoints.size beträgt: "+ 
                 directionPoints.size() + LocAddress + String.valueOf(i));
     String LocTime = directionPoints.get(i).get("TimeStamp");
     Parkmarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LocLat,  
                LocLng)).title(LocAddress);
             Parkmarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon));
     } //loop ends here
 googleMap.addMarker(Parkmarker);
```

EDIT:

you have to instantiate a `new ParkMarker` inside the loop every time, otherwise the same reference will get updated

EDIT:
try to use

```
googleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LocLat,LocLng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark‌​er_icon) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it still doesn't work. The Log in load locations shows only the Address of the last Marker for each loop. I think there is something going wrong in LocationParser class but I just don't get it.

Comment: Can you give me some example Code? I started programming about three month ago and I really don't know how to instantate a new Parkmarker.

Comment: can you try googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LocLat,LocLng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon));

Comment: Changed it but still doesn't work. The Arraylist seems to contain only the values of only one marker.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I'm verry stressed at the moment.

Comment: what is the count of the arraylist after you have added the markers (using your previous code of adding markers to array list), does it contain all the markers or just one marker

Comment: The Arraylist.size in LocationParser class is 9 but it seems to contain the values of one Marker 9 times. EDIT: The Log in LocationParser shows the different parsed Values. There seems to be a problem while adding the Values into the Hashmap

Comment: that is because, you are creating the map outside the for loop. you need to instantiate a new hash map inside the for loop and add to the arraylist, otherwise only the reference will get updated and all values would be same as last value

Comment: God I'm such an Idiot. Thank you so much dude. I knew it was something simple but just couldn't see it. Big Thanks from Germany and a Merry Christmas.

Comment: same to you :) . i hope you understand why that was a problem

Comment: Yes I do understand it. I've added the same Map to the list everytime. Thanks again.

Comment: :( you stole my check mark and gave it to somebody else. merry xmas anyways :P

Comment: you can +1 the answers you liked, not accept , but +1 . i see you are new here :)

Comment: It's just OK, maybe you can vote up my answer instead of accept it

Comment: thats right, I'm new here. Thats why upvoting isn't possible for me yet. Sorry Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

In the method

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDirection(Document DirektDoc) {
....
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
// creating new HashMap
    try{ 

       ....

       LocationItems.add(map);
   }catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("LocationParser", e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

You always operate one hashmap instance and add this instance to List .
So you need move the creation of HashMap into the loop like this:

```
   public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDirection(Document DirektDoc) {
   ....

   for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   // creating new HashMap
    try{ 

       ....

       LocationItems.add(map);
   }catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("LocationParser", e.getMessage());
   }
```

}